# Synchronise tables in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I got 7 tables in sql server 2005 having relation with each other based on primary key and foreign keys. I need to make a new table which will contain columns of all the 7 tables together. I need this new table to be synchronised every time with the main 7 tables. What is the best way to do this in Sql server 2005 or 2008..

Comment: view will make it slow for execution since i will be using data from this table frequently..

Comment: Why do you think using a view will be slow? Have you actually done some testing and observed that it's definitely slow? If it is, have you looked into indexed views?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are what you should use for automatic updation of a table based on event in same table or other tables..

See example on this [link](http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1653067-how-create-trigger-updates-row-another-table.html)

Comment: i dont want to use triggers because they will slow down the main tables for insertion..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create new table which will contain all column of 7 tables and insert/update in common table as per changes of any table of 7.

This process does not affect of speed of process.

Another way is to create a View  containing 7 table column.

Comment: better then u will choose first one option

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a new table like this:

```
select * into newtable from 
t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
...
t6 join t7 on t6.id=t7.id
```

insert:
here t is one of the 7 tables where data is modified

```
2.insert into newtable(col1 col2..)
  select col1,col2..from t
```